# How to access variable which is inside a click function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a function in document.ready() like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var reason = $("#DropDown_Select").val() // i can access this 
    var delreason;
    $('#btnDeleteRow').click(function () {
        delreason = prompt("Are u serious");
        alert(delreason); //Here i am getting entered prompt value sucessfully 
    });


    //when i try to use the delreason else where in my code i am getting " UNDEFINED "
    //Actually i need this so i can pass it to controller 

    "sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData/?start=" + delreason //delreason here is undefined 

});
```

In controller part i am using like :

```
 var value = Request.QueryString["start"]; //undefined value coming
```

EDIT 1 :

```
var delreason='';
$(document).ready(function () {
    var reason = $("#DropDown_Select").val()
    var oTable;
    $('#btnDeleteRow').click(function () {
        delreason = prompt("r u serious");
        alert(delreason);
        debugger;
    });

 oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({ 
 "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler"
});

oTable.oTable.makeEditable({

     "sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData/?start=" + delreason  // is there any problem here
});
```

Any workaround is pretty much appreciated . i am unable to test the delreason in sDeleteUrl wheather it is present or not but one thing i am not getting anything at controller when tried to extract string .

Comment: Declare `var delreason` outside `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: So what is your real issue here?

Comment: Use window.delreason instead of var delreason;

Comment: when i pass some static value in place of delreason i am getting value at controller via query string extraction . Regards

Comment: "sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData/?start=" + delreason //delreason here is undefined ??? where is this statement in ajax??

Comment: added aditional info possibly make things clear . regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delreason` is declared inside a closure (function body) and only exists inside this function block.

If you try to access this variable form code inside the same closure (the body of the function executed on document ready), the variable is available.

If you try to access it from somewhere else, it won't be available.

One posibility is to define this variable on the global scope, which in a browser is the window object, like this:

```
window.delreason = '...';
```

or simply

```
delreason = '...'; // without the var
```

But if you do so, take into account that you're polluting the global scope, and that's usually not a good idea (you can get conflicts with other scripts). However, if you don't have other scripts and it's a very simple page it could be acceptable (although not very acceptable).

Another option is to create a hidden field, and use jquery to set and get the value in this field:

```
<input type='hidden' id='delreason'/>
```

In your js:

```
$('#delreason').val('written value');

var delreason = $('#delreason').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your real issue is that you want to access delreason everywhere you must declare it outside document.ready

Answer (score 1):

`var delreason;` need to declare outside `$(document).ready()` to access it globally.

You can understand the difference from [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NEb4v/)

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 - use the window global object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var reason = $("#DropDown_Select").val() // i can access this 
    $('#btnDeleteRow').click(function () {
        window.delreason = prompt("Are u serious"); 
        alert(window.delreason);
    });
});
```

Approach 2 - declare delreason in the global scope (outside the closure):

```
var delreason = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
    var reason = $("#DropDown_Select").val() // i can access this 
    $('#btnDeleteRow').click(function () {
        delreason = prompt("Are u serious"); 
        alert(delreason);
    });
});
```

Comment: when i keep reason in place of delreason i am getting dropdown value sucessfully but not the prompt text i am getting to controller ..